# new Date() function returns wrong value

Tags: javascript

The new date(code) returns working value,Please Help me

```
var cdt = new Date();

dob = "15/01/1999";//From date picker
alert(dob);

    var bdy = dob.split("/");
    var by = bdy[2];
    var bm = bdy[0];
    var bd = bdy[1];

    var dob = new Date(bd, bm, by);
alert(bd+","+bm+","+by);
alert(dob);
```

Date format changed for new date() function:

[image]

Values return by that function:

[image]

Comment: `var bm = bdy[0];` it should be `bdy[1]`. You've interchanged month with date

Answer (score 1):

`new Date()` method takes three parameters on **constructor**.

The order of parameters is following: `year`,`month` and `day`.

Something like this: `var date=new Date(1999,01,01)`.

```js
var cdt = new Date();
dob = "15/01/1999";//From date picker

var bdy = dob.split("/");
var by = bdy[2];
var bm = bdy[1];
var bd = bdy[0];
var dob = new Date(by, (bm-1), bd);
console.log(bd+","+bm+","+by);
console.log(dob.toLocaleDateString());
```

Comment: For me it prints:
15,01,1999
"1999-01-14T23:00:00.000Z"

Answer (score 1):

You could use [JavaScript ISO Dates format](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_date_formats.asp) that is the format: `yyyy-mm-dd`, see following example please:

```js
var dString = "15/01/1999";
console.log("From date picker", dString);

var bdy = dString.split("/").reverse().join("-")
var dob = new Date(bdy);

console.log("Javascript Date" , dob);
```

I hope it helps you, bye.

Comment: I think it's a bit of a waste going from a string to numbers to another string which will then be parsed into numbers yet again internally in `Date` anyway…

Comment: String to numbers? When?

Comment: Correction: string to split string to combined string to string parsing.

Comment: @Alessandro wouldn't it be better to switch date format using `dString.split("/").reverse().join("-")`?

Comment: @barbsan Thanks, I like it (and I edited the code) anyway the point is he need to use constructor with ISO Dates format

Comment: (new DateTime("2008-13-02");) - function Not returns any values

Comment: @Madhan What is the thirteenth month?

Comment: sorry iam on testing so only i change it , Actually it's 01-